# Count of categorical values grouped by another column with dplyr in R

Tags: r, aggregate, dplyr

I want to summarize a df by location names. The data looks something like this:

```
location <- c("NY", "NC", "KA", "TX", "AZ", "NC", "SC", "ND", "SD", "MN","WA","MA","VT","CA","OR","NJ","OH","MI","IL","GA","FL")
tree_type <- c("pine", "birch", "maple", "palm")
df <- data.frame(location = sample(location, 20, replace = TRUE), 
           tree_type = sample(tree_type, 20, replace = TRUE),
           density = runif(20, min = 24, max = 365), 
           income = runif(20, min = 37000, max = 62000))
```

What I want is this:

```
   location mean(density) mean(income) birch maple palm pine
1        AZ      38.44009     52032.95     0     0    1    0
2        CA     136.85112     42243.35     0     1    0    0
3        GA     101.24081     53405.60     2     0    0    0
4        IL     172.02651     46368.42     1     1    0    0
5        MA     198.69868     51117.18     0     0    0    1
6        MI     153.93358     60425.87     1     0    0    0
7        MN     185.05276     46468.68     0     0    1    0
8        NC     181.42187     46007.93     1     0    2    0
9        NJ     302.66541     59316.94     0     0    2    0
10       OR     303.88283     48497.03     0     0    0    2
11       SC      84.05136     50348.41     0     1    0    1
12       SD     158.47423     57894.27     0     0    1    0
13       VT     126.32967     42853.04     0     0    1    0
```

I did it this way:

```
require(dplyr)
require(reshape2)
df_quantvars <- df %>% group_by(location) %>% summarise(mean(density), mean(income))
df_catvarslong <- as.data.frame(table(df[1:2]))
df_catvarswide <- dcast(df_catvarslong, location ~ tree_type, value.var = "Freq")
final_df <- left_join(df_quantvars, df_catvarswide, by = "location")
```

Is there no way to do this within the `dplyr` group_by idiom? At the risk of sounding stupid, I tried to do this:

`df_quantvars <- df %>% group_by(location) %>% summarise(mean(density), mean(income), table(df[1:2]))`

What am I missing?

Comment: ` summarise(mean(income), mean(density), 
              birch=sum(tree_type=="birch"),
              maple=sum(tree_type=="maple"),
              palm=sum(tree_type=="palm"),
              pine=sum(tree_type=="pine"))`

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: Here's another attempt `df %>% group_by(location) %>% summarise(mean(density), mean(income)); df.table <- aggregate(tree_type ~ location, data = df, FUN = table); left_join(df, df.table, by = "location")`.

Comment: Don't forget that `dcast` can aggregate directly.  I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for (is using `table` required?), but you could do this all with a `group_by`, `mutate` and `dcast`: `df %>% group_by(location) %>% mutate(mean(density), mean(income)) %>% dcast(location + \`mean(density)\` + \`mean(income)\` ~ tree_type, fun.aggregate = length)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This response is a little late but I already put some work into it. To keep it all in one go was a little tricky. This seems to work:

first I use the `group_by(location, tree_type)` to count all of the trees, then I use the `group_by(location)` to get the desired means. I then remove the original density & income categories with `select(-c(density, income)` and am left with duplicate rows but the correct aggregate counts. I then remove the duplicates with `distinct()` and then use `spread()` from the `tidyr` library to convert to wide format as you requested.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  arrange(location)%>%
  group_by(location, tree_type)%>%
  mutate(Count = n())%>%
  group_by(location)%>%
  mutate(MeanDensity = mean(density), 
         MeanIncome = mean(income))%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  select(-c(density, income))%>%
  distinct()%>%
  spread(key = tree_type, value = Count, fill = 0)
```

This gives me:

```
  location MeanDensity MeanIncome birch maple  palm  pine
     (fctr)       (dbl)      (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1        AZ   244.18094   57474.94     0     0     1     0
2        FL    51.90693   42425.36     0     0     0     1
3        GA   341.18643   49385.44     0     0     0     2
4        IL   258.11124   37101.36     0     1     0     0
5        KA   267.92430   59699.20     1     0     0     0
6        MA    87.48623   60632.98     1     0     0     0
7        MI   197.18310   58837.00     0     0     0     1
8        NC   362.48531   50857.42     0     0     1     0
9        ND   315.57415   51465.06     0     0     1     0
10       NJ   233.72886   55877.40     0     0     1     1
11       NY   283.41522   49275.58     0     1     0     1
12       OH   350.23362   40901.73     0     0     1     0
13       OR   267.68415   38954.04     0     2     0     0
14       SC   260.12169   52837.10     0     1     0     0
15       SD    76.29782   54986.76     0     1     0     0
16       VT   341.80646   44547.77     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: Or `df %>% count(location, tree_type) %>% spread(tree_type, n, fill=0L) %>% left_join( df %>% group_by(location) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean), -tree_type) )` which avoids needing to type the names income and density.

Comment: Nice! Sometimes this stuff is like a rabbit-hole.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in stages. First, find all the means.

```
x <- df %>% 
  group_by(location) %>% 
  summarise(mean(density), mean(income))

location `mean(density)` `mean(income)`
   <fct>              <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 AZ                 150.          44667.
 2 FL                 262.          53719.
 3 IL                 308.          41077.
 4 KA                 183.          48432.
 5 MI                 192.          61649.
 6 NC                 210.          50838.
 7 NJ                 223.          49958.
 8 OH                 357.          57881.
 9 OR                 336.          52582.
10 SC                 234.          40414.
11 SD                  54.8         48203.
```

Separately, count all the tree types, then spread.

```
y <- df %>% group_by(location, tree_type) %>% 
                count() %>% 
                spread(tree_type, n, fill = 0L) #the fill option is great for replacing NAs with 0s

# A tibble: 11 x 5
# Groups:   location [11]
   location birch maple  palm  pine
   <fct>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1 AZ           0     1     0     1
 2 FL           0     0     1     0
 3 IL           0     0     0     1
 4 KA           2     0     0     2
 5 MI           0     0     1     0
 6 NC           1     2     0     1
 7 NJ           1     0     1     0
 8 OH           0     0     1     0
 9 OR           1     0     0     0
10 SC           1     0     0     0
11 SD           1     0     1     0
```

Finally, join the two dataframes together. They'll join automatically by the common location value they both share. I used right join, but you could use `left_join` too.

```
right_join(x, y)

Joining, by = "location"
# A tibble: 11 x 7
   location `mean(density)` `mean(income)` birch maple  palm  pine
   <fct>              <dbl>          <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1 AZ                 150.          44667.     0     1     0     1
 2 FL                 262.          53719.     0     0     1     0
 3 IL                 308.          41077.     0     0     0     1
 4 KA                 183.          48432.     2     0     0     2
 5 MI                 192.          61649.     0     0     1     0
 6 NC                 210.          50838.     1     2     0     1
 7 NJ                 223.          49958.     1     0     1     0
 8 OH                 357.          57881.     0     0     1     0
 9 OR                 336.          52582.     1     0     0     0
10 SC                 234.          40414.     1     0     0     0
11 SD                  54.8         48203.     1     0     1     0
```

Three stages seems pretty verbose. We could combine everything into one statement.

```
# This part is equivalent to stage one
df %>% 
  group_by(location) %>% 
  summarise(mean(density), mean(income)) %>% 
# This part is equivalent to stage two and three.
  right_join( 
               df %>% group_by(location, tree_type) %>% 
               count() %>% 
               spread(tree_type, n, fill = 0L)  
             )
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it?